# Trying to iterate through pandas df with multiple row conditions

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

Apologies in advance. I am very new to python.
I have created a pandas df indexed with a date timestamp. I would like to iterate through all the rows with conditions based on a particular column and that same column in the next row. Based on the example below I would like to check the ‘Streak’ column against an absolute value, eg.3 and then check the next row to see if the streak column turns negative.

I am struggling to look at the next row due to timestamp index. I have tried `.shift()` and numerous attempts with `loc` and `iloc` as well as `Timedelta`. They issue with the latter being that there isn’t a consistent difference between the timestamp on each row.

My df looks like

```
             Security      Difference     Buy/Sell     Streak  Price
Date 
2019-02-25       2330           500.0            1          1  238.0
2019-02-26       2330           400.0            1          2  239.0     
2019-02-27       2330           200.0            1          3  239.5
2019-03-05       2330          -600.0           -1         -1  233.0
2019-03-06       2330           190.0            1          1  234.0
```

The code I have tried but failing with is

```py
streaklength = 3
for index, row in mergeddf.iterrows():
    currentrow = mergeddf.index.get_loc(index)
    If (mergeddf.iloc[currentrow,’Streak’] >= streaklength & (mergeddf.iloc[Currentrow + 1, ‘Streak’]) == -1:
        Do something
```

EDIT - in turns of output I would like to get the ‘Price’ column for the original row and the price price for a column a fixed number of rows later and return that ratio.

So for my original example where the fixed row move n=2. I would like to return a variable ouput1 (239.5) and ouput2 (234) and return the ratio of output1/output2

Comment: provide expected output.

Comment: do you mean `df.loc[df.Streak.eq(3).shift().fillna(False),'Streak'].lt(0)` ?? this returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, what you want is `(df.Streak >= 3) & (df.Streak.shift(-1) < 0)`.

Changing the first row in your own example a little bit to ensure that both criteria are met, this gives the following:

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]:
            Security  Difference  Buy/Sell  Streak  Price
Date
2019-02-25      2330       500.0         1       3  238.0
2019-02-26      2330       400.0         1       2  239.0
2019-02-27      2330       200.0         1       3  239.5
2019-03-05      2330      -600.0        -1      -1  233.0
2019-03-06      2330       190.0         1       1  234.0

In [16]: (df.Streak >= 3) & (df.Streak.shift(-1) < 0)
Out[16]:
Date
2019-02-25    False
2019-02-26    False
2019-02-27     True
2019-03-05    False
2019-03-06    False
Name: Streak, dtype: bool
```

To also answer the edited question, you can then use this mask to get the relevant outputs:

```
mask = (df.Streak >= 3) & (df.Streak.shift(-1) < 0)
df['Output1'] = df[mask].Price
df['Output2'] = df[mask].Price / df.shift(-2)[mask].Price
```

which results in the following:

```
In [139]: df
Out[139]:
            Security  Difference  Buy/Sell  Streak  Price  Output1   Output2
Date
2019-02-25      2330       500.0         1       3  238.0      NaN       NaN
2019-02-26      2330       400.0         1       2  239.0      NaN       NaN
2019-02-27      2330       200.0         1       3  239.5    239.5  1.023504
2019-03-05      2330      -600.0        -1      -1  233.0      NaN       NaN
2019-03-06      2330       190.0         1       1  234.0      NaN       NaN
```

or

Comment: Thanks. When I try this solution in my code I get the truth value of a series is ambiguous.

Comment: Did you use `and` instead of `&`, or remove the parentheses?

Comment: No - exactly as shown above. I get the same error when trying the response from @anky_91

Comment: I can replicate your output outside of my if statement within `.iterrows` loop but once inside I get the ambiguous series error

Comment: @NS7274: The idea here is to avoid the loop entirely and test the conditional on all rows *at once*.

Comment: Updated the answer to also answer the edited question, which might make it clearer how this would work.